# how to hide cmd shell window?

Tags: windows, cmd

on start up i have a bat file run routine things for me

however, the black console pops up and stays open until everything is finished....

anyway to hide it and run it in background ? so it shouldn't appear minimized or system tray.

Comment: refer this article : https://www.howtogeek.com/131597/can-i-run-a-windows-batch-file-without-a-visible-command-prompt/

Answer (score 5):

You can use a VBS script to achieve this. Either write all your code as VBS, or call your batch file like this:

```
'launch.vbs
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "mybatch.bat", 0
WshShell = Null
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a shortcut to the file.  On the new shortcut: Right click -> Properties.  Go to the Shortcut tab, and choose "Run: Minimized."  (This is assuming you're on WinXP).

Comment: I was going to suggest the same, but then noticed that the original poster did not want it to "appear minimized or [in] system tray".

Comment: This fixed my issue..  I just needed it to stay out of the way when I'm working in the OS.  For hiding the window completely I would use a vbscript suggested by Craig.

Answer (score 2):

[This link](http://www.howtogeek.com/131597/can-i-run-a-windows-batch-file-without-a-visible-command-prompt/) should help you as helped me. I used the second solution that uses a program named `quiet.exe`

To use, just call `quiet.exe program params_if_has`.

My use example: `quiet.exe php script.php`

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do that but if you are using the scheduler to run the batch file you can select "don't interact with desktop" when creating the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming your file to `.cmd` instead of `.bat`.

Or, if you're executing a `.exe` try:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\SomeProg\someprog.exe"
```

Note: When using "start" you have to be at a command prompt.

Comment: Renamed it to a .cmd and had the same effect.  Tried to Ctrl+R and in the run box typed start "" "C:\script.cmd" which errored out with can not find start.

Answer (score 0):

I once had a little program which could hide windows based on their title. So my startup batch first set a unique title with `title` and then called the other program to hide the window with said title. Worked fine but involves a little programming.

If you don't want to go that way, then you should use the Task Scheduler as tr4656 noted.